# Read file contents present in sharepoint

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint-online, docx2txt

I have a directory with n number of subdirectory in each on a sharepoint. Each sub directory has files either with doc or docx extension. I want to read the text(possibly read the content as plane text to parse every string). I know docx2txt but it needs the file to present on local machine(i feel so). Is there any better way?

I am using graph api to scan/browse sharepoint directory.

Looking for some direction please.

```
import requests
import pathlib

# Copy access_token and specify the MS Graph API endpoint you want to call, e.g. 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups' to get all groups in your organization
#access_token = '{ACCESS TOKEN YOU ACQUIRED PREVIOUSLY}'

url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/......"
headers = {
  'Authorization': token_result['access_token']
}

consentfilecount=0
clientreportcount = 0
graphlinkcount = 0

while True:
    
    try:
      graph_result = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
      graph_result.raise_for_status()
    except:
      token_result = client.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
    
    headers = {
      'Authorization': token_result['access_token']
    }
    

    if ('value' in graph_result.json()):
      for list in graph_result.json()['value']:
        for ele in finalReportNames:
          if ele.lower() in list["name"].lower():
            clientreportcount +=1
            response = requests.get(list["webUrl"],headers=headers)#{"Authorization": f"Bearer " +token_result['access_token']})
            print(response)
            print(list["name"])
            print(list["webUrl"])
            print(pathlib.Path(list["name"]).suffix)
        #print(graph_result.json())
      if('@odata.nextLink' in graph_result.json()):
        url = graph_result.json()['@odata.nextLink']
        graphlinkcount += 1
      else:
        break

print(consentfilecount)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get SharePoint access token and download your directory url**

```
import requests

import docx2txt

acc_tok = get_sharepoint_access_token()

dir_url = ""your directory url"

**Create headers and try again**

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
}

response = requests.get(dir_url, headers=headers)

files = response.json()["value"]

for file in files:

    file_url = file["@content.downloadUrl"]

    file_name = file["name"]
    
    with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
        
        response = requests.get(file_url, headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"})
        
        f.write(response.content)

**Now convert them to plain text** 


for file_name in os.listdir():

    if file_name.endswith(".docx"):

        with open(file_name, "r") as f:

            text = docx2txt.process(f)
```

Comment: I am getting <Response 403>. Somehow not able to authorize it.

Comment: Create headers.

Comment: so the first authorization works well. I am able to use graph api to get exact file location there.The request.get where we are passing the fike url and the headers is not working. Let me know your thoughts...i will trying out ways meanwhile.

Comment: If the file is large try downloading it using SharePoint SDK method.

Comment: {"error_description":"Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was
thrown."}

Comment: The error says that audience uri of access token doesnt match expected audience uri of SharePoint site. So authenticate with your right user credentials or try again with a new access token .

Comment: Yeah, I am trying out in Postman as well but no luck.